# Effective DataSet for NLP practice

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, text-processing

Please share a link to a dataset that is effective for practicing NLP (Natural Language Processing).

I am beginner level and would like to improve my skills.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

NLP is a very broad field, so if you want a specific dataset, you need to name a specific NLP problem (such as NER, sentiment analysis, summarization, etc.), and probably a specific language in which you want to solve this problem.

But still, there are places to look for NLP datasets and problems in general:

- the NLP tag on Kaggle: https://www.kaggle.com/tags/nlp
- a list of NLP datasets: https://github.com/niderhoff/nlp-datasets
- a similar question on DS StackExchange: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/6798/list-of-nlp-challenges